# How to get rid of WebKitFormBoundary in uploaded file

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, multipartform-data

I'm implementing a **file upload** in a web application.

The front-end is written in **angularJS** and uses the **angular-file-upload** package (the one that can be found at this link https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload).

The back-end is **Java / Jersey** Web Services.

#### My Question is:

The uploaded file contains a **WebKitFormBoundary** header and footer, like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarylqskdjlqksdjl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="foo.bar"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

Therefore, I'm not sure whether I'm uploading a file or a request. And of course, my back-end application considers that the uploaded files are corrupted and would not display them unless those lines are removed (for now manually).

**Bottom line is : how do I get rid of that header and footer in the uploaded file?**

Here are some code samples.

#### Front-End

Once again: angularJS angular-file-upload

```
item.headers = {
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + item.file.name + '"',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
};
```

#### Back-End

and Java / Jersey

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("someurl/{fileName}")
public Artifact uploadArtifact(InputStream uploadedStream, @PathParam("fileName") String fileName) throws Exception;
```

### Note

I'm wondering if the `Content-Disposition: attachment` in my angularJS part could be what's messing it up?

And that it should rather be `Content-Disposition: form-data`?

Thx in advance!

Comment: We used both angular-file-upload and java backend in our project. What i know is that you don't need to manipulate any header in ajax request. You should handle it in java, maybe you need a library there to handle these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place [`@FormDataParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html) annotation in order to properly handle boundary.

```java
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("someurl/{fileName}")
public Artifact uploadArtifact(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails,
    @PathParam("fileName") String fileName) throws Exception;
```